# LdapInvalidDnException: unexpected token:

Tags: java, apache, ldap

I am getting the below exception while doing a ldap search and wondering if it is a problem with api or something I need to fix ?

```
16:41:19,290 ERROR [com.synchronoss.readytogo.handler.ZipFileHandler] (Thread-2038 (HornetQ-    client-global-threads-24851093))     org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapInvalidDnException: unexpected token: :: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapInvalidDnException: unexpected token: :
at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.name.ComplexDnParser.parseDn(ComplexDnParser.java:58) [api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M16.jar:1.0.0-M16]
at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.name.Dn.parseInternal(Dn.java:1374) [api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M16.jar:1.0.0-M16]
at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.name.Dn.<init>(Dn.java:285) [api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M16.jar:1.0.0-M16]
at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.name.Dn.<init>(Dn.java:211) [api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M16.jar:1.0.0-M16]
at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.search(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1506) [api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M16.jar:1.0.0-M16]
```

My DN value is `"cn=device:abc:abc xyz x+:abc/cing/evitareul:4.2.2/jdq39/257669.4:user/release-keys,ou=Permissions,dc=r2g,dc=dcs,dc=zzz,dc=com"` contains a plus sign, I believe that is causing the issue \, any help advice will be appreciated on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two things: 1) The plus sign + indicates the that the DN is multi-valued.2)  `:` is not allowed in an attribute name.

Simply put, one portion of the DN is:

```
cn=device:abc:abc xyz x
```

and the other portion is:

```
:abc/cing/evitareul:4.2.2/jdq39/257669.4:user/release-keys,ou=Permissions,dc=r2g,dc=dcs,dc=zzz,dc=com
```

The second portion of the multi-valued valued of the RDN (cn) is incorrect. Since the second portion is also an RDN (multi-valued DN), that portion should start with an attribute type/name:

```
cn=:abc/cing ...
```